# Which open source font is closest to Airbnb's Cereal Font?

Tags: typography, font-recommendation

I love [Airbnb's Cereal Font](https://airbnb.design/introducing-airbnb-cereal/) but I'd like to find something totally open source for my project. Which font is closest?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you have enough with just two styles, [Montreal](https://fontlibrary.org/es/font/montreal#Montreal-Bold) via fontlibrary.org

[image: Montreal]

---

Google Font [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat)

[image: Montserrat]

Comment: ..and what did Airbnb pay to avoid the tragedy of simply using this font? Sometimes my own industry amazes me. https://airbnb.design/introducing-airbnb-cereal/ - really? Nothing else would possibly work? Food on our tables I suppose, so I can't complain.

Comment: More or less the same that Sears Canada paid for its incredible new, avant-garde, futuristic and completely renovated [logo](http://marketingmag.ca/brands/sears-unveils-revamped-logo-181905/) design

Answer (score 1):

You can go for **[Manrope](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Manrope)** as well as **[Inter](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter?query=inter)**. Both are free of cost, available under Open Font License at [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).